# Can I easily change the colour of a bootstrap theme

Tags: website-design, css, bootstrap

**I am looking for a bootstrap theme for a web application.** The application is going to manage properties for landlords, so it is going to be mainly a collection of tables and forms -- and so the "Admin & Dashboard" category seems to fit what I am looking for.

https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product-category/admin-dashboard/

**But I would like a red site and the "Admin & Dashboard" bootstrap the themes are all blue**. I have been told that you cannot easily change the colour of the a bootstrap theme, because it would have been developed using shades of a colour and therefore you would need to change many colours in the theme.

I have considered a grayscale site and have a red logo. But then I need to find a grayscale bootstrap theme.

I want to use a bootstrap theme as it is -- and not have to change it. But I also want a red site. **What are my options?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a personal rant. Sorry :)

I think that bootstrap is a necessary pain.

On the very first lines of the stylesheet you have something like this:
[image]

Which was a "politician" promise. "If you vote for me, you can change one variable and all the site will be updated!"

But then, you see that all over the page you have specific values everywhere.

[image]

They could have used another color notation like HSL, but no...

---

So the truth is that you need to update your stylesheet yourself.

Use the inspector to find a specific color value and replace it with your new value.

You probably need to prepare first a small table for your conversions.
For example, when you first encounter a tone of blue, you probably do not know if it is the lightest tone or the middle tone. So making a small table first will allow you to visualize the changes you need to make.

Back up your original files first.

---

I will try to expand this answer with some additional resources to ease the process.

Comment: Thanks @Rafael. That is very helpful!